# Warning: Illegal string offset error message

Tags: php

I'm getting this error message:

> "Warning: Illegal string offset 'password' in
>   /home/u/u6882969/www/hittarum.nu/wp-content/themes/wm-mediation/page-login.php
>   on line 165"

I have the same code on another site which is working, but in this case it doesn't work. Can someone please tell me what to do?

```
<?php
if (!$error["password"]):
?><label for="password">Lösenord</label><?php
else:
?><label class="error" for="password"><?php
    echo $error['password'];
?></label><?php
endif;
?>
```

I'm using PHP version 5.5.17 and MySQL version 5.0.67

Comment: `var_dump($error)` yields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that `$error["password"]` doesn't exist. If that's the case, you'll see the error. Instead, replace this:

```
if (!$error["password"]):
```

...with:

```
if (empty($error["password"])):
```

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer to close up your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `$error` is a string and not an array. A string is an array of chars, however, so consider this:

```
$error = 'string';
echo $error[1]; // 't'
echo $error[3]; // 'i';
echo $error['password']; // illegal string offset
```

You should `var_dump($error)` to see what's actually there, it's most likely a string containing the error and not an array that's exploded by fields.